# RMAN connect error - db reporting incompatible target version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

I'm trying to use RMAN to backup an Oracle database without a backup catalog.  When attempting to connect to the target database I'm getting an error message that my RMAN version is incompatible with my database version.  This seems odd to me as my RMAN version is 11.2.0.1 and my database version is 11.2.0.3 but the RMAN error states that I need to use RMAN 8.0.4.0 to 11.1.0.7.  Why is my database reporting version 11.1.0.7 to RMAN when it should be reporting as 11.2.0.3?

```
C:\>rman

Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue May 24 09:48:07 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

RMAN> connect target SYS/oracle@tnsname

Recovery Manager incompatible with TARGET database: RMAN 8.0.4.0 to 11.1.0.7 req
uired
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-06429: TARGET database is not compatible with this version of RMAN

RMAN> exit


Recovery Manager complete.

C:\>sqlplus SYS/oracle@tnsname

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue May 24 09:49:24 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

SQL>
```

Comment: What does `show parameters compatible` report?

Comment: It's coming back as 11.1.0.0.

Comment: That explains why you are getting the error. Is there a reason why compatible has been set to 11.1.0.0 ?

Comment: No reason I know of. I'm guessing it was a sloppy upgrade by the prior administrator.  There's a maintenance window this weekend. Do I just change the pfile or is it more involved than that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change [the `compatible` initialisation parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams035.htm) to 11.2.0 (or higher). You can do that with [`alter system`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2014.htm):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE = '11.2.0' SCOPE = SPFILE;
```

The change won't take effect until you restart the database. If you don't have a server parameter file for some reason then you can change it in the pfile instead, but you still need to bounce the database to pick up the change.

Make sure you understand the setting and its implications, [from the upgrade guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/intro.htm#BHCJHGFA) and [admin guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm#ADMIN11112). It sounds like it was just missed after upgrading from 11gR1, but if you can make sure it wasn't left on the old version for a reason before changing it.

Comment: Thought this was the answer and marked it as such, but after changing the pfile entry to 11.2.0.0.0 and bouncing the db I'm still seeing the rman error.  I'm going to change the compatible setting to 11.2.0 in tonight's maintenance window to see if things change. Thoughts?

Comment: @LeeGreco - are you booting from the pfile, or an spfile? The pfile is ignored usually if you have both. (I should have mentioned that this suggested fix isn't something I can actually test; I think it's right but I've beenwrongbefore...)

Comment: We're definitely booting this instance from a pfile.  show parameters compatible picked up the new value.  Yesterday I just changed the 1 to a 2 on the compatible setting which left me with 11.2.0.0.0.  I'll change it this evening to just 11.2.0 and see what happens.

Comment: @LeeGreco - hmm, shortening it won't help, I think. Not sure what else it might be needed; haven't seen anything helpful on MoS...

Comment: Still doesn't work connecting from my admin workstation which is running RMAN 11.2.0.1.  Rebooted the server and logged into the server console.  RMAN on server comes up as version 11.1.0.7. Curious. Seems the db was upgraded but the utilities weren't.  Attempted to connect and received 
`ORACLE error from target database:
ORA-04063:  package body "SYS.DBMS.RCVMAN" has errors
ORA-06508:  PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called "SYS.DBMS_RCVMAN"

error executing package DBMS_RCVMAN in TARGET database
...
RMAN-06429:  TARGET database is not compatible with this version of RMAN`

Comment: Not sure then, sorry. Also not sure how rman wasn't upgraded. Maybe you'll get better advice if this gets migrated to [DBA.SE]. (Or you can ask directly there, including a summary of what you've found; but if you do that then delete this question, as cross-posting isn't liked much).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112961/discussion-between-lee-greco-and-alex-poole).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to an incomplete upgrade.  Apparently not all of the catalog update scripts were executed properly.  Here's what fixed it for me:

```
SQLPLUS /nolog
SQL> CONNECT / AS SYSDBA
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/dbmsrman.sql
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/prvtrmns.plb
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/dbmsbkrs.sql
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/prvtbkrs.plb
```

Answer (score 0):

Error
While connecting with RMAN Command window getting the following errors:

```
RMAN-06438: error executing package DBMS_RCVMAN in TARGET database
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS =============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-06429: TARGET database is not compatible with this version of RMAN
```

Cause
“SYS.DBMS_RCVMAN” package has error which causing the problem. May be package is in-valid state.

Solution

1. We tried to check in target database if it’s invalid.

   select OWNER, STATUS, substr(OBJECT_NAME,1,40), OBJECT_TYPE from DBA_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME IN ('DBMS_RCVMAN', 'DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE' ) ;
2. Try to recompile it and check the status.

   @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
3. If 2nd steps is not working the package is not become valid, then try to re-create the package by executing following steps from SYS user.

   @?/rdbms/admin/dbmsrman.sql
   @?/rdbms/admin/prvtrmns.plb